# I would like to check if I did well the translation of the writings on an ancient seal, into English

Tags: translation, seal

The seal, a longitudinal one in green Jade, represents a roaring imperial lion with the mouth towards the sky. On the frontal part has one column of chinese characters. It seems to be from the Empress Wu Zetian (690-705).

I did my research, and find out: 些度產唐, Xiē dù chǎn táng, "Tang Dynasty".
唐 Tang
產 chan
度 Du
些 Xie

Please find attached the picture.

I would like confirmation.

Many Thanks in advance.
[image: Wu Zetian Seal Front Text]

Comment: I can’t recognize the last character, but the first 4 character should be 塘Tang 盧Lu 老Lao 人Ren

Comment: @BoomingBones: Thank you very much for your comment. The last one could be: 生 Sheng?. And the whole sentence: 塘盧老人生: Táng lú lǎo rénshēng. Tang Lu Lao Sheng. Thnks

Comment: The last character is most definitely not 生 (http://www.sfds.cn/751F/) 'to live; give birth to; raw' but rather 乍=作 (http://www.sfds.cn/4F5C/4/) 'to make — made by'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO this reads 塘盧老人作 'made by the old guy, Tang Lu'.

Comment: Thank you, John. Then Who was Tang Lu, the Old?  Army General (1520-1570): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lu_Tang 
塘盧老人作: Táng lú lǎorén zuò. Old man Tanglu made